# How to loop input field based on array

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I have an array like below

```
standardInput:any = [{val:'1'},{val:'2'},{val:'3'}];
```

When i loop it in my view

```
<div class="form-group row text-right" *ngFor='let row of standardInput' >{{row.val}}
     <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f"></label>
         <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-9" >
                  <input class="form-control" name="roles" [formControl]="form.controls['service_standard_sub_heading']" [(ngModel)]="row.val" id="email-h-t" type="email">
               </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeInputs('standard',i)">Remove</button>
               </div>
           </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

The output is :3 3 3,it is showing only the last object in the array for the 3 iterations.I am not able to understand what's the reason.Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using template-driven form, if not, let me know and we can look at a solution for model-driven form :)

In forms, the `name` attribute needs to be unique. Even though the `ngModel` is unique, Angular doesn't really care about it, but looks at the name attribute instead. Since you are using a template-driven form and `ngModel`, I see no need to use `formControl` here, you can just rely on the the `ngModel` and `name` attribute instead. So, to get the unique name attribute, we can bind the `row.val` to it, like so:

```
[name]="row.val"
```

So your complete template would look like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group row text-right" *ngFor='let row of standardInput'>
    <input class="form-control" [name]="row.val" [(ngModel)]="row.val">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How did it go with this code? Was template driven form the correct way? :)